# android stop audio when phone lock after play about 10-20 min

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a app radio, which use exoplayer
Almost good work, but when phone in background radio play about 10-20 min and stop and I turn phone radio continue play. How can I fix it programatically?
Mediaplayer have a method like setWakeMode(), but I do not find same to Exoplayer. Sorry for my English

Comment: When in the background, as per my knowledge to continue the media you need a foreground service.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with **exoPlayer**, when phone screen locked **AudioTrack** shutdown after few minute, So you can add WakeLock or WifiLock in your code to keep **exoplayer** running in background,Even if the phone’s screen is locked.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this,
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

        wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "wifiLock");
        wifiLock.acquire();

        if(exoPlayer == null){
            //Your code Exoplayer her
        }
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)) { 
        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            exoPlayer.stop();
        }
        if (wifiLock != null && wifiLock.isHeld()) {
            wifiLock.release();
        } 
   }
}
```